# Can't configure kotlin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've properly configured `kotlin` plugin in eclipse. But I can't open a `kotlin` file. It says: **`Plug-in org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui was unable to load class org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui.editors.KotlinFileEditor.`**

[When I tried to crate a `kotlin` file this happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2X3o.png)

Comment: You would get better answer if replace tag "java" with "kotlin".

Comment: Creating new tag "Kotlin" requires at least 300 reputation. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

use eclipse neon from older packages. 
Kotlin plugin for eclipse is not working for current release.

Jetbrain gave up 3rd party support so there is little chance for this issue get resolved. 
Regard it as deprecated.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/current-state-of-eclipse-plugin/4979